# WoW Severe graphical Corruption on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wine, games

I get those graphical glitches when running WoW 4.2.0 with wine (Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64), in a Dell XPS 15(L501X), even with ironhide.

Anyone can help me?

- CPU: Intel Core i5-460M
- 4gb RAM
- because it's a Dell XPS 15(Optimus Technology), i have 2 graphic cards:

  - An Intel HD 460M integrated graphics card, which driver is i915
  - A nVidia GeForce GT 420M, ALREADY with propietary drivers
- Running Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64 with custom XFCE Desktop
- Wine 1.4 rc6(Emulating winxp)
- corefonts and vc2005 installed on Wine

[image]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WorldofWarcraft this may help

Comment: I've tried that, in fact, i tried it first, and searched in the fine web for this, but no answers :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that before, I cannot remember what fixed it.  However there is a list of things you can disable.  I'd first start with turning off triple buffering and making sure you're using OpenGL.

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24878